# jQuery mobile range slider; how to allow user to input value larger than the max value

Tags: jquery, mobile, slider, range

I have some jQuery Mobile range sliders that help the user with common values (i.e. 0-10), but they also need to be able to key in a larger value sometimes and I can't seem to find any info on that.  For example:

```
<input id="txtTest" type="range" value="0" min="0" max="10" />
```

This helps with values 1-10 but does not allow them to key in 20 in cases that they need larger numbers?

Comment: Can include `html` , `js` at Question ?

Comment: It's in the documentation: https://api.jquerymobile.com/rangeslider/. Post your HTML, like @guest271314 requested.